# vector, v.end() and v.begin()

Tags: c++11

```
vector <int>v;
vector <int>:: iterator it,it1; 
it=v.begin();
it1=v.end();
v.insert(it,12); // in this line doesn't matter what i write it or it1
it=v.begin(); it1=v.end(); // here *it=12, also it is first element and it1 = last element + 1
v.insert(it1,15); // if i write it instead of it1, then v contains 15 12
it=v.begin(); it1=v.end();
cout<<*(it+1); // this line outputs 15;
```

if my comments are correct, then how v.insert(v.end(), any number); can be correct?

Comment: `v.insert(v.end(), number);` is perfectly valid - it will add a new item to the end of the vector, same as what `push_back` will do.

Answer (score 1):

`iterator insert( iterator pos, const T& value );` inserts the element **before** the specified position.

So here it will insert at the back, and then the `end` position will shift by one.

Your `it1=v.end()` will be invalidated by the `insert`, so you'll need to re-set it. (Thanks @Mgetz)

To insert into an empty vector, you can still insert to `end`. Just because `end() == begin()` in an empty vector doesn't mean they're set to the same thing.

Comment: it's important to note that the iterator is invalidated by the `insert`, so while you can use it to insert you need to call `end` again to do the same afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Never debug comments. Always debug the code. :)

[`std::vector::insert(iterator, value)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) inserts the value before the iterator passed in. Since `std::vector::end()` is passed to `insert()`, this inserts 15 before the end of the vector - that is, after 12. Therefore when the element after the first element is printed, this should print 15.

Comment: so as i guess insert( add element on iterator - 1 position  , value )

Comment: but how can i use insert() when vector is empty?

Comment: @David: You can insert to the `end`